# Prove that the functions are uniformly continuous, given a specific interval?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm asked to "prove that each of the following functions is uniformly continuous on the indicated interval".

1. $\frac{x^{18}+6x^{12}+12x^6+18}{\left(x-6\right)\left(x-12\right)\left(x-18\right)}$ on (24, 30)
2. $\frac{sinx}{x}$ on (0, 1)

Is there a trick to solving these questions?

Or - is it enough to use the theorem that states that  if f is continuous on the interval [a,b], then f is uniformly continuous on [a,b]? Would stating that these functions are continuous because their denominator is not equal to 0 in the given interval be enough to prove that they are uniformly continuous?

I've also tried using the definition of uniform continuity but the first question gets way too complicated and I get stuck on the second one.

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: See here for your second example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259766/prove-or-disprove-that-fx-sin-x-x-is-uniformly-continuous-over-the-interv

Comment: And Yes re: first problem. The (24,30) interval contains none of the singularities

Comment: What do you mean by singularities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ on $(0,1)$

**Thm: A function is said to be uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ iff it can be extended to a continuous function on $[a,b]$.**

Clearly, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$

The continuity at $0$ reflects the differnetiability of $\sin x$ at $0$, which is $\cos0=1$. i.e.
$$1=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x - \sin0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$$
and obviously $f(x)$ is continuous at $1$.
Therefore we conclude that $f(x)$ can be extended to $[0,1]\implies f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

$g(x)=\dfrac{x^{18}+6x^{12}+12x^6+18}{\left(x-6\right)\left(x-12\right)\left(x-18\right)}$ on $(24,30)$

Clearly, $g$ is continuous on the interval without $x=6,12,18$,
which implies $g$ is continuous on $[24,30]$, then it's uniformly continuous on $(24,30)$.

Comment: If you want the proof for that theorem, just tell me in the comment, and I'll write it for you.