# Generally proving continuity of an extended function

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let a function G be
\begin{equation*}
     G(x)= \left\{
            \begin{array}{ll}
                 &  \frac{\sin{x}}{x}, &\text{if }x\neq0 \\
                 &  1, &\text{if }x=0\\
            \end{array}\right.
    \end{equation*}

I want to prove that it is continuous everywhere.

##### My attempt

My initial thought was to use that a function is continuous iff $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a), \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ to prove that it is continuous at $x=0$. This is quite easily done by observing the limit from left and right respectively to prove that the limit exists.

I can do so by applying L'Hopital's rule s.t.

$$\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{\cos{x}}{1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\cos{x}}{1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

Therefore the limit exists, is equal to 1 and proves continuity at $x=0$.

Then I tought about using that $\frac{f}{g}$ is continuous if $g(x)\neq0\forall x$; however, I am hindered by the fact that $x$ intersects the x-axis (and is equal to 0 at $x=0$), or am I misinterpreting this definition for continuity?

Is there another definition I can easily apply to prove continuity. I was also looking at some epsilon-delta definitions; however, these seem more complicated than necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: It's already continuous everywhere except for $x=0$. You already delt with this case so there is nothing more to do.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't I have to prove it rigorously?

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259766/prove-or-disprove-that-fx-sin-x-x-is-uniformly-continuous-over-the-interv

Comment: This is a ratio of two continuous functions so it's continuous

Comment: The ratio of two continuous functions is continuous at all points where the denominator is not $0$. That shows $\frac {\sin x}{x}$ is continuous everywhere except $0$. At $0$, you have to prove continuity by other means, which is what you did in showing that the limit at $0$ is $1$. L'Hopital's rule is rigorous. What more do you think you need.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you, your comment explains everything I was confused about. I thought that the definition of continuity only applied if g is not equal to 0 at any points; however, I now understand that it applies everywhere except at 0. If you write an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful to remember that continuity is defined at points, even when we talk about it as a property of the function as a whole. The requisite theorem is:

- Let $f, g$ be two functions defined on a neighborhood of $p$, with $g(p) \ne 0$. If $f$ and $g$ are both continuous at $p$, then so is $\frac fg$.

By this we know that $G$ is continuous at every point of $\Bbb R$ except $0$. The theorem says nothing one way or the other about the continuity of $G$ at $0$.

That can be shown by the definition of continuity at a point: $G$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0} G(x) = G(0)$, which you demonstrated.

So $G$ is continuous at every point of its domain. Or more succinctly, "$G$ is continuous".